# Ошибка в алгоритме сложения 2 n-битных чисел

Tags: c++

даны два массива по n элементов, где каждый из них равен 1 или 0, т.е. все элементы массива записанные в ряд представялют число в двоичном виде. Пытаюсь реализовать функцию, которая возвращает массив из n + 1 элементов, содержащий результат сложения:

```
    int* summ(int n, int* a1, int* a2) {
    int* farr = new int[n + 1];
    int d = 0;
    for (int i = n - 1; n <= 0; i--) {
        int j = i + 1;
        if ( (a1[i] == 1) && (a2[i] == 1) ) {
            d++;
            farr[j] = 1;
            continue;
        }
        if (((a1[i] == 1) || (a2[i] == 1)) && d > 0) {
            farr[j] = 1;
            d--;
            continue;
        }
        if (((a1[i] == 1) || (a2[i] == 1))) {
            farr[j] = 1;
            continue;
        }
        else farr[j] = 0;

    }
    return farr;
}
```

Однако, выполняя распечатку полученного массива

```
int* farr = summ(n, arr1, arr2);
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
        cout << " " << farr[i];
    }
```

выходит, что каждый элемент - мусорное значение, а не 1 или 0.
В чем ошибка?

Comment: Очень странный алгоритм. вот прямо с первых строчек. 1 и 1 у вас почему то дают 1, хотя должны дать 0 плюс перенос из пред. разряда и перенос в следующий. при этом перенос не может никогда накапливаться а ваше d++ вполне может дать на выходе 2. второй if то же неправильный.

Comment: Это какое-то академическое задание? Потому что то, что Вы описали (а именно `даны два массива по n элементов, где каждый из них равен 1 или 0, т.е. все элементы массива записанные в ряд представялют число в двоичном виде.`) в С++ есть ничто иное как  [std::bitset](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/bitset/bitset/). Т.е. есть уже готовый велосипед в стандартной библиотеке (STL)

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i = n - 1; n <= 0; i--) {
```

Поскольку `n` - это длина массива, то она почти всегда больше нуля. А цикл по твоему коду будет выполнятся только при отрицательной или нулевой длине - т.е. никогда.

Comment: Действительно, это объясняет почему все элементы в массиве были рандомными - потому что они и не изменилясь, однако после изменения знака неравенства на противоположное программа просто не печатает значения этого массива.

Comment: @derzz, я и не говорил, что нужно изменить знак на противоположенный. Если тебе нужно обойти массив с конца, то код должен быть примерно такой: for(int i=n-1; i>=0; --i)